# When I use for loop: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-2.7

when I run a source code file of a software, a error raised.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gwava_annotate.py", line 297, in <module>
    df = annotate(vf)
  File "gwava_annotate.py", line 255, in annotate
    encode_feats(vf, ENCODE_FEATS),
  File "gwava_annotate.py", line 41, in encode_feats
    for entry in annots:
  File "pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx", line 787, in pybedtools.cbedtools.IntervalIterator.__next__ (pybedtools/cbedtools.cxx:11123)
  File "pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx", line 652, in pybedtools.cbedtools.create_interval_from_list (pybedtools/cbedtools.cxx:9208)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I run the source code one by one till the error happened again.

```
>>> for entry in annots:
...  fs = entry[4].strip(',').split(',')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx", line 787, in pybedtools.cbedtools.IntervalIterator.__next__ (pybedtools/cbedtools.cxx:11123)
  File "pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx", line 652, in pybedtools.cbedtools.create_interval_from_list (pybedtools/cbedtools.cxx:9208)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

`annots` is a instance, you can see

```
>>> type(annots)
<class 'pybedtools.bedtool.BedTool'>
```

I tried to print it

```
>>> print(annots)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pybedtools/bedtool.py", line 1072, in __str__
    for i in iter(self):
  File "pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx", line 787, in pybedtools.cbedtools.IntervalIterator.__next__ (pybedtools/cbedtools.cxx:11123)
  File "pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx", line 652, in pybedtools.cbedtools.create_interval_from_list (pybedtools/cbedtools.cxx:9208)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And

```
>>> len(annots)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pybedtools/bedtool.py", line 1080, in __len__
    return self.count()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pybedtools/bedtool.py", line 2283, in count
    return sum(1 for _ in iter(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pybedtools/bedtool.py", line 2283, in <genexpr>
    return sum(1 for _ in iter(self))
  File "pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx", line 787, in pybedtools.cbedtools.IntervalIterator.__next__ (pybedtools/cbedtools.cxx:11123)
  File "pybedtools/cbedtools.pyx", line 652, in pybedtools.cbedtools.create_interval_from_list (pybedtools/cbedtools.cxx:9208)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So I check its attributes

```
>>> dir('annots')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

So, I put `annots` content to a string

```
>>> a = ['DNase:26039,H3K4me3:13995,POLR2A:9215,H3K4me2:8024,H3K9ac:6869,H3K27ac:5904,H3K27me3:4816,H3K4me1:4622,FAIRE:4462,H2AFZ:3052,CTCF:2356,H3K36me3:1766,H3K79me2:1469,TAF1:1264,TBP:798,YY1:689,NFKB1:664,MYC:578,MAX:565,USF1:496,SP1:415,HEY1:409,SIN3A:405,ELF1:396,EP300:383,E2F1:377,H4K20me1:369,JUND:330,E2F6:315,EGR1:299,CEBPB:279,PAX5:251,CHD2:227,FOXA1:227,RAD21:218,TCF12:206,E2F4:205,STAT3:202,REST:200,GABPA:197,USF2:197,POU2F2:194,SLC22A2:194,TCF7L2:193,MXI1:183,NR3C1:180,HNF4A:177,GTF2F1:174,GATA1:169,EBF1:167,SPI1:167,HDAC2:163,TRIM28:154,CCNT2:149,HMGN3:141,GATA2:132,FOSL2:130,FOS:129,IRF4:116,ZNF263:116,TFAP2C:115,POLR2A_elongating:114,STAT1:109,RFX5:108,NRF1:107,H3K9me3:99,POLR3A:98,BCLAF1:97,FOXA2:97,IRF1:97,ELK4:87,HNF4G:87,SMC3:87,TFAP2A:87,ZBTB7A:75,TAF7:73,SRF:72,ZEB1:70,ETS1:69,JUN:66,BCL3:64,BRCA1:64,NR2C2:64,SMARCB1:64,BATF:60,GTF2B:58,MEF2A:57,SREBF1:56,TAL1:55,RXRA:54,NFYA:49,HSF1:47,BHLHE40:46,PBX3:44,NFYB:42,RDBP:42,SIX5:42,STAT2:39,ZNF143:38,ATF3:36,MAFK:34,IRF3:31,ZBTB33:29,SETDB1:24,CTCFL:23,SP2:23,SREBF2:21,CTBP2:16,GATA3:16,MEF2_complex:15,NFE2:15,SMARCC1:15,SUZ12:15,JUNB:14,SMARCA4:14,BDP1:13,ERALPHAA:10,FOSL1:10,H3K9me1:10,SIRT6:10,MAFF:9,NANOG:8,SMARCC2:8,BCL11A:4,BRF2:4,PPARGC1A:4,THAP1:4,Eralphaa:2,NR4A1:2,ESRRA:1,FAM48A:1,GTF3C2:1,POU5F1:1,PRDM1:1,ZNF274:1']
```

it worked

```
>>> for test in a:
...  test1 = test[4].strip(',').split(',')
...  print(test1)
['e']
>>> for test in a:
...  b = test.strip(',').split(',')
... 
>>> b
['DNase:26039', 'H3K4me3:13995', 'POLR2A:9215', 'H3K4me2:8024', 'H3K9ac:6869', 'H3K27ac:5904', 'H3K27me3:4816', 'H3K4me1:4622', 'FAIRE:4462', 'H2AFZ:3052', 'CTCF:2356', 'H3K36me3:1766', 'H3K79me2:1469', 'TAF1:1264', 'TBP:798', 'YY1:689', 'NFKB1:664', 'MYC:578', 'MAX:565', 'USF1:496', 'SP1:415', 'HEY1:409', 'SIN3A:405', 'ELF1:396', 'EP300:383', 'E2F1:377', 'H4K20me1:369', 'JUND:330', 'E2F6:315', 'EGR1:299', 'CEBPB:279', 'PAX5:251', 'CHD2:227', 'FOXA1:227', 'RAD21:218', 'TCF12:206', 'E2F4:205', 'STAT3:202', 'REST:200', 'GABPA:197', 'USF2:197', 'POU2F2:194', 'SLC22A2:194', 'TCF7L2:193', 'MXI1:183', 'NR3C1:180', 'HNF4A:177', 'GTF2F1:174', 'GATA1:169', 'EBF1:167', 'SPI1:167', 'HDAC2:163', 'TRIM28:154', 'CCNT2:149', 'HMGN3:141', 'GATA2:132', 'FOSL2:130', 'FOS:129', 'IRF4:116', 'ZNF263:116', 'TFAP2C:115', 'POLR2A_elongating:114', 'STAT1:109', 'RFX5:108', 'NRF1:107', 'H3K9me3:99', 'POLR3A:98', 'BCLAF1:97', 'FOXA2:97', 'IRF1:97', 'ELK4:87', 'HNF4G:87', 'SMC3:87', 'TFAP2A:87', 'ZBTB7A:75', 'TAF7:73', 'SRF:72', 'ZEB1:70', 'ETS1:69', 'JUN:66', 'BCL3:64', 'BRCA1:64', 'NR2C2:64', 'SMARCB1:64', 'BATF:60', 'GTF2B:58', 'MEF2A:57', 'SREBF1:56', 'TAL1:55', 'RXRA:54', 'NFYA:49', 'HSF1:47', 'BHLHE40:46', 'PBX3:44', 'NFYB:42', 'RDBP:42', 'SIX5:42', 'STAT2:39', 'ZNF143:38', 'ATF3:36', 'MAFK:34', 'IRF3:31', 'ZBTB33:29', 'SETDB1:24', 'CTCFL:23', 'SP2:23', 'SREBF2:21', 'CTBP2:16', 'GATA3:16', 'MEF2_complex:15', 'NFE2:15', 'SMARCC1:15', 'SUZ12:15', 'JUNB:14', 'SMARCA4:14', 'BDP1:13', 'ERALPHAA:10', 'FOSL1:10', 'H3K9me1:10', 'SIRT6:10', 'MAFF:9', 'NANOG:8', 'SMARCC2:8', 'BCL11A:4', 'BRF2:4', 'PPARGC1A:4', 'THAP1:4', 'Eralphaa:2', 'NR4A1:2', 'ESRRA:1', 'FAM48A:1', 'GTF3C2:1', 'POU5F1:1', 'PRDM1:1', 'ZNF274:1']
```

How can I fix this problem?
The software introduced by a Nature Method paper, and I do not change any code.Somebody has used it(I know from the paper's cite), but it stops here when I run.

There are many question aboud "list index out of range", but I can not get useful information.

Comment: If the error raises in the code you didn't write, it should be reported to the person who wrote it. Does this software have an issue tracker somewhere? If yes, you should use it and wait until the issue is solved (or try to fix it yourself)

Comment: Thank you. I will  try to fix it and wait the anwser from the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted with somebody maintain the `pybedtools`, and he told me that it was the `BedTools` version make this error happen. I should change it to developer version.